# How to apply a custom function to grouped data in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I am workig with PySpark and have a dataframe looking like this example below:

[image]

I want to group by req and apply a function on each group by.
My function looks something like this:

```
def function(df):
   ...
   model = modelxy.fit(df)
   transformed = model.transform(df)
   ...
   return df
```

I tried solving it the following way but the map function only works with RDDs. However, my function excepts a dataframe to work on.:

```
df_new = df.groupy('req').map(function) #I want to apply the function on each group by and store results in new dataframe
```

What is the best way of applying a function to grouped data?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a pandas udf?

Comment: @mck Isn't the Spark way more performant? At least that's what I thought. I will change my question to also accept pandas udf solutions.

Comment: Yes, Spark is more performant than pandas udf, but the prerequisite is that your function can be written in Spark. It seems you're calling some Python machine learning libraries, so I think a udf is needed (unless you refactor your code to use Spark ML instead).

Comment: @mck No actually I am using a machine learning model implemented in Spark. The entire code within the function is written in PySpark and I am using PySpark libraries. However, the model I am using is also available in a Python library and I could change my code to fit pandas udfs, if that helps me run my code properly.

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood. I didn't know you're using Spark ML.

Comment: What kind of function do you want to apply on the data? An aggregating function?